# Why is jQuery .focus not firing?

Tags: javascript

In the code below, the first `alert()` fires, but the second one never fires when I click the textfield assigned with the 'clear' class.

Does anyone have a clue why this happens?

```
(function ($){

   alert('TEST 1');
   var clearMePrevious = '';

   // Clear input on focus.
   (function ($)('.clear').focus(function() {
     alert('TEST 2');
     /*
      if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) {
        clearMePrevious = $(this).val();
        $(this).val('');
      }
      */
    }(jQuery));

}(jQuery));
```

The problem is just in the inner code, as `$document.ready()` fires the `TEST 1` alert.

I have tried different variations of `(function ($){});` and `function (jQuery){});`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formatting made me twitch, so I fixed it up for you.

[Drupal JS Coding Standards](http://drupal.org/node/172169)

Also you weren't using a behavior, so I fixed that too:

[Javascript in D7](http://drupal.org/node/756722)

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.textFieldClearer = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var clearMePrevious = '';

      // clear input on focus
      $('.clear').focus(function() {
        if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) {
          clearMePrevious = $(this).val();
          $(this).val('');
        }
      });

      // if field is empty afterward, add text again
      $('.clear').blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
          $(this).val(clearMePrevious);
        }
      });
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I misunderstood the documentation: `$` is accessible inside a `(function ($){}` block. The trick is that you really need to add the `$(document).ready()` call to have the selectors accessible after the page loads.

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var clearMePrevious = '';

    // clear input on focus
    $('.clear').focus(function()
    {
        if($(this).val()==$(this).attr('title'))
        {
            clearMePrevious = $(this).val();
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
    // if field is empty afterward, add text again
    $('.clear').blur(function()
    {
        if($(this).val()=='')
        {
            $(this).val(clearMePrevious);
        }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```